# What is a Silhouette Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

I was going through a study in which I found something called a dilated Silhouette Neural Network. I want to know what it is, what it can do, and how it is better from a CNN?

Link to the journal: [Link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016783962100011X)